# How can I set BaseRequestOptions for HTTP_PROVIDERS while using the upgradeAdapter?

Tags: angular

I know that when bootstrapping Angular2 normally, the bootstrap call can be used to provide default HTTP request options like so:

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})]);
```

However, this does not seem to work when using the `upgradeAdapter.bootstrap()` method:

```
//This throws ugly errors.
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['td', [HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})], {strictDi: true});
```

I did try passing the array to the `upgradeAdapter.addProvider()` method, but the headers I added in `MyOptions` did not get sent.

```
//This doesn't seem to do anything at all.
upgradeAdapter.addProvider([HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})]);
```

Is there another way to provide these default request options?

Answer (score 0):

When bootstrapping with UpgradeAdapter, set providers or use your own classes, such as with useClass or useValue, with adapter.addProvider(). Here's an example of bootstrapping a hybrid angular app with a modified RequestOptions, to set a custom header:

```
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

class MyRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.headers.append('CUSTOM_HEADER', 'Hello World');
    }
}

adapter.addProvider({ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyRequestOptions });

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["MyNg1ModuleName"]);
});
```

Note that although UpgradeAdapter accepts as third argument a "config" param, it's not actually the Angular2 providers configuration.